# how can i get user information using facebook sdk 4.1 in ios?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using a pre-built login UIButton of Version 2.3 of facebook integration.

**Problem:** Getting null result, when fetching user details.

```
-(void) loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {

            FBSDKGraphRequest *request =[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil];
            [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
    {
        // Handle the result
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
    }];

    FBSDKProfile *profile = [[FBSDKProfile alloc]init];

    }
}
```

Comment: if result is coming nil, then surely there is an error, can you log it?  if (!error) {
         NSLog(@”fetched user:%@”, result);
      } else {    NSLog(@”error=%@",error)      }

Comment: yes i can log in and log out but cant fetch user details...i used self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]; permission is that right?

Comment: Permission is right, but I said you to log the error out here. just set a break point log the error

Comment: 2015-05-15 15:28:05.278 FacebookLoginDemo[27415:190601] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 7.)

Comment: thats my view didd load...

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
    
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
    self.loginButton.delegate=self;
    self.loginButton.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
    
    [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
    
    
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Continue login");
    }

    
}

Comment: First Compare your app id in .plist file with FB bundle id are they are same?
then check is your  app is  in a sandbox mode?

Comment: Just check whether you have permitted your app while login from device, you can directly check in Facebook setting of your simulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];


     //Default FB Button
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"getFacebookData" object:nil];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

**ViewDidLoad of viewController**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(getFacebookData) name:@"getFacebookData" object:nil];

 FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
 loginButton.center = self.view.center;
 [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

**Add this method in view controller**

```
- (void)getFacebookData{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, name, id, gender"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this, you will get your answer
To get profile picture -

```
FBSDKProfilePictureView *profilePictureview = [[FBSDKProfilePictureView alloc]initWithFrame:_imageView.frame];
[profilePictureview setProfileID:result[@"id"]];
[self.view addSubview:profilePictureview];
```

To get profile picture and email information

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture, email"}] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id res, NSError *error)
 {
    if (!error) {
        NSString *pictureURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[res objectForKey:@"picture"]];

        NSLog(@"the EMail = %@", [res objectForKey:@"email"]);

        NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictureURL]];
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
    else
    {
         NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }}];
```