# FBSDKGraphRequest use of undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

Though I have imported FacebookSDK like: `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`, but it says:
use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKGraphRequest'.

The code I wrote is simple:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                      initWithGraphPath:@"/{user-id}/albums"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
            // Handle the result
        }];
```

Let me know what may I be missing?

Comment: what  procedures you have followed to import facebook sdk?It is missing ;)

Comment: @Vizllx I am unable to put: <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>, I don't know why. I tried editing, but of no gain.

Comment: Could you able to import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> framework? Is it automatically detecting when you type?

Comment: Yes, It's automatically detecting and framework is properly added. And infact I am able to log in through facebook too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 4.X Facebook has split the SDK in 3 parts:

[Per documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x):

> The SDK is now composed of three frameworks, `FBSDKCoreKit`,
>   `FBSDKLoginKit`, and `FBSDKShareKit`.
>
> `FBSDKCoreKit` provides core SDK
>   functionality such as Graph API Requests, access tokens, and App
>   Insights.
>
> `FBSDKLoginKit` provides functionality to log people in, and
>   only requires `FBSDKCoreKit`.
>
> `FBSDKShareKit` provides functionality to
>   share, and only requires `FBSDKCoreKit`.

As for your question:

> Requests - `FBSDKGraphRequest` and `FBSDKGraphRequestConnection` are in
>   `FBSDKCoreKit` and provide helpers to access the Graph API

So basically you need to import `FBSDKCoreKit` in your file:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```

Comment: Thanks Lefteries, it helped. I deleted old FacebookSDK and used the new version 4.X.

Answer (score 1):

For login into Facebook using new SDK 4.1 You have to add the FBSDKLoginkit and FBSDKCoreKit Frameworks in your project.

Then import the below header files into your ViewController:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

For more information you can refer [the facebook official document here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3) or you can refer these answers

1. [First answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29473323/4140018)
2. [Second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30256269/4140018)

Eventhough facebook official document is best.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Your answer is right too. But I am unable to mark both the answer correct.

Comment: That's fine dude. Happy coding.